# Matplotlibs Configure Subplot Widget not working with Figure.add_axes()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib instance integrated in PyQt.
My approach is based on Eli Benderskys [way](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2009/qt_mpl_bars.py) of integrating matplotlib with PyQt.

If I add the the plot to the figure with add_axes (so that I can set its geometry), the configure subplot widget from the toolbar does not work.

```
from matplotlib import Figure
fig = Figure((9.0, 6.0))
axes = fig.add_axes( [0.14, 0.13, 0.76, 0.75])
```

If however I add the plut with

```
fig.add_subplot(111)
```

It works seamlessly. However then I am not able to set the initial geometry of the subplot (or at least I don't know how).

Is this a bug in matplotlib? How can I make the widget work and still set the inital geometry of the subplot?

For reference: I am talking about the following widget:[image: configure subplot]